# Running a piece of code in background android

Tags: android, background-process

This is what I require :

I have a TV app which can be force stop by user. in this scenario, I want to run a separate application which will trigger my Tv app service and I need to execute a function which will hardly take 1-2 seconds.

is there any way to trigger this piece of code from other application in background ? I was planning to use foreground service here but I need to send a notification also. I don't want this notification as it is going to take 1-2 seconds only.

Comment: Why do you need another application to run this service? What's stopping you from running the service when your application is killed?

Comment: Because in case of force stop, my app onStop() method is not executing.

Comment: I am finding that hard to believe that onStop is not getting called. And I also think onStop is not the right place to start your service. You should call it in onDestroy. If it is also not getting called then you should first investigate that.